# what's the complexity of finding all intersection in interval tree(red black based)?

Tags: algorithm

So there's lots of question of Stackoverflow about interval tree but I didn't find any about the complexity of operation `findall(Itv)`, that is, given an interval `Itv`, find all the intervals intersecting with `Itv`, in a Red black based augmented Interval Tree. 

I learn from Robert Sedgewick's coursera course Algorithm that this operation can be done in `O(RlgN)`, where `R` is the number of intersecting intervals and `N` is number of Nodes. But I'm not sure what algorithm corresponds to this complexity (most of the stuff I've google only mention how to know if `Itv` is intersecting with any interval). I did find an `findall(Itv)` operation in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#CITEREFCormenLeisersonRivestStein2009)   (section Java example: Searching a point or an interval in the tree), my only problem about it is that, I don't know if it's `O(RlgN)` and I can't prove it.

Anyway, if anyone can find an efficient way of `findall(Itv)` in bbst augmented interval tree(NOT CENTERED INTERVAL TREE), or prove that the wiki algorithm is `O(RlgN)`, or point me to any related literature, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Wiki algorithm (which was cribbed from CLRS), is O(R log N). It's somewhat tricky to analyze because of the one-procedure implementation and the placement of the checks, so let me present and analyze a closely related version (the original can be recovered by moving some tests between parent and child calls and by replacing `search1` with `search`):

```
class Node {
    // Binary search tree sorted on start.
    // The interval at this node is [start, end).
    // maxEnd is the maximum value of end in this tree.
    int start, end, maxEnd;
    Node left, right;

    void search(int p, Collection<Node> results) {
        if (p < start) {
            if (left != null && p < left.maxEnd) left.search(p, results);
        } else {
            // p >= start
            if (left != null && p < left.maxEnd) left.search1(p, results);
            if (p < end) results.add(this);
            if (right != null && p < right.maxEnd) right.search(p, results);
        }
    }

    void search1(int p, Collection<Node> results) {
        // Precondition:
        //   p < maxEnd
        //   for every node x in this tree, p >= x.start
        if (left != null && p < left.maxEnd) left.search1(p, results)
        if (p < end) results.add(this);
        if (right != null && p < right.maxEnd) right.search1(p, results);
    }
}
```

Except for the calls to `search1`, the method `search` is a normal-ish descent in a binary search tree. The cost exclusive of these calls is O(log N) because the tree height is O(log N).

The reason that I split out `search1` is that, for every node on which `search1` is called, at least one descendant is added to the results (i.e., the node `x` with `x.end == this.maxEnd`). I claim that there exists a constant c such that for all possible invocations, the running time of `search1` is bounded by c R' H, where R' is the number of results in the subtree and H is the height of the subtree. Since the calls to `search1` by `search` are for disjoint subtrees (hence the sum of R' values is bounded by R), and H is O(log N), the total running time is O(R log N).

The claim is proved by induction. Let RL be the number of results in the left subtree and RR be the number of results in the right subtree. The running time recurrence is

```
c + c RL (H - 1) + c RR (H - 1) ≤ c + c R' (H - 1) ≤ c R' H,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      left call     right call
```

where `c` is chosen to cover the non-recursive work done in `search1`, since R' ≥ 1. That we can assume R' ≥ 1 was the reason to split `search1` in the first place; proving a bound of c (R' + 1) H directly on `search` won't work because both of the recursive calls need the +1.

Comment: Thanks David! This is super helpful!